# sonar.coverage.exclusions and integration tests coverage

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I had a maven module that got analyzed for both Unit-tests and Integration-Tests coverage.

I specifically added `sonar.coverage.exclusions` to the maven module that I wanted to exclude from coverage analysis.

It worked well with the UT, but the module was still analyzed for IT coverage and I got weird behavior where the overall coverage is smaller than the UT coverage because it looks at more code.

I'm using SonarQube 4.5 with java plugin 2.9.1.

Comment: Have you had any luck with that?

Comment: no... not really. sorry

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154350/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-sonarqube-from-calculating-and-presenting-the-overall) and no answers either. There is actually an [open issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5050) about this. Our best bet is to accept this or use `sonar.exclusions` instead (excluding the classes completely from SonarQube, instead of excluding them only from the coverage calculation).