# Is there a way to prevent SonarQube from calculating and presenting the overall coverage?

Tags: java, testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube5.1

I'm excluding from my coverage some classes using `sonar.coverage.exclusions`. However, this only works for unit tests (there is [an open issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5050) and [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239340/sonar-coverage-exclusions-and-integration-tests-coverage) about this) and, since I don't have any integration tests, I end up with an overall coverage smaller than my unit tests coverage, as can be seen in the image:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent SonarQube from calculating this overall coverage? I have the impression that I've seen projects before where SonarQube would only present the unit tests coverage. Since I can't fix this, I want at least hide it. I don't (and won't) have any integration tests, so the unit tests coverage is all that matters, the overall coverage is irrelevant.

I'm using SonarQube version 5.1.2 and JaCoCo (Maven plugin) version 0.7.5.201505241946.

#### EDIT:

I just realized that if I use `sonar.exclusions` instead of `sonar.coverage.exclusions` I'll fix my problem. But `sonar.exclusions` also excludes the classes from the whole SonarQube analysis, and I want to exclude them only from the coverage calculation.